# PLSQL - Add days to date in format dd/mm/yyy +1

Tags: sql, date, plsql, toad

I want to write a PLSQL query in the following way:

```
Select ...
FROM ...
WHERE
Date = '06/FEB/2011' + 7(days)
```

Im new to PLSQL, I've seen solutions such as date+1, but that requires by date to be inside a variable.
I tired putting into a variable like the following:

```
declare date1  date;
begin
date1 := '06/FEB/2015';
select *
from 
    ...
where
        DATE_LABEL = date1 + 1;

end;
```

But it keeps giving me an error that is expecting an INTO statement in the SELECT. Im not sure what this means.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `DATE` data type is not stored as a string, so hard-coding to a specific format is not advised, as the format may change based on your database/session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` value.  A more portable expression is to include the data format mask in the query, such as:

   ```
   select * 
   from table Foo
   where date_col = to_date('06/FEB/2011','DD/MON/YYYY) + 7;
   ```

The date format masks values are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

2. When executing a query within a pl/sql block, you have have to define somewhere for the result set to be stored upon return.  You need to use a cursor for that.  In your example, if you only have one row to return, you can declare a placeholder for the result as you did, but need to use the INTO keyword in you select:

   ```
   declare date1  date;
   begin
   date1 := '06/FEB/2015';
   select date_col
   into   date1
   from  table  -- etc.    
   end;
   ```

I would suggest to read some PL/SQL tutorials, which cover these basic concepts in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, an even more portable solution is to use the standard Ansi date literal. This will be recognized by a large number of DBMSs. So your code would look like this:

```
Select  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   DateField = date '2011-02-06' + 7;
```

or

```
WHERE   DateField = (date '2011-02-06') + 7;
```

just to make it clearer.

The date literal *must* be in the form 'yyyy-mm-dd' and is not affected by system date format settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADDDATE(date, INTERVALE INTEGER DAY)
```

You should write the number of days also you can use Month, Minute, Hour.